# Image Overlay for Classified Images

Tags: arcmap, sentinel-2, overlay, image-classification

I   created 5 classified images for year 2019-2023 as shown: -
[image]
Fig: Classified image of Sentinel-2 for 2019

I have also prepared the classified image for 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023 like above. The problem remain is that If I worked for individual image from 2019-2023, then I need to calculate accuracy (Kappa) for my work that will make work more cumbersome. Because, I have satellite image of Landsat too. Thus, to make my work brief and to calculate image accuracy (Kappa) in brief; is there any way that these images can be overlap and a final combined image can be produced with classification being preserved??